# Issue converting halogen desk lamp to LED

Tags: led, led-driver, lamp, halogen

I have a halogen desk lamp with a three position rocker switch with a central off position and either side representing a different dimming setting. It has a transformer with two coils  connected to each side of the rocker.

The transformer started buzzing which I believe was due to the separating of the plates. I can't get a replacement so I rather than through it in the bin I wanted convert the lamp to LED.

I'm not great with electrics but got most of the way there I just can't explain one issue.

I removed the transformer and replaced it with a 20W LED driver. I snipped and heatshrunk one side of the rocker switch and connected the other to the LED driver. I replaced the halogen bulb with an 11W LED bulb. It works as expected in that the light does not turn on when in the off or heatshrunk positions, it turns on when the switch is in the correct position. The issue is when I return the switch to off, the lightbulb stays on.

Can anyone explain what's going on?

See more information below, the switch is shrouded so I can't see what type or positions.

Wiring
[image: Wiring]

LED DRIVER
[image: LED driver]

Shrouded rocker switch
[image: Rocker switch]

LED Bulb
[image: LED Bulb]

I believe the fuse is a simple 1A.

Let me know if any other information would help.

Comment: Unlikely as we don't know which components you used and how you wired them. Also, it sounds like you have replaced the safe mains transformer with potentially unisolated LED driver, so you better know what you are dealing with, as touching the lamp can be lethal.

Comment: @MarkyMark and I would like to see a list of components and photos added to the question if possible.  Please click the edit link below your question.

Comment: After you turn the switch off, does the LED stay on indefinitely, or does it slowly dim over time?  If it slowly dims, this would be because capacitors in the LED driver hold a charge, and slowly discharge through the LED after the switch is turned off.

Comment: Usually, the switch would go in the one input to the led driver. The led driver would always be connected to the led. This way, when the switch is off, the led driver is off, too.